# apex date not valid error

Tags: apex, date

Sorry if asking same question again but really facing the issue with the bad input date I am new to salesforce if someone can guide me how to handle leap year and bad date in apex.
If someone enters wrong date then my code should handle it but I am getting error as date not valid.I have batch class so the entire batch is failing because of the one record. **Input date: 02/29/1969**
1969 is not the leap year

```
tD = tI.mid(48,8);
    
                tD = tD.replace('\u00A0',' ').trim();
            
                if(tD.length()==8 && tD!='00000000' && tD!='99999999' && tD.isNumeric()==TRUE){
                    tF = tD.mid(4,2)+'/'+tD.right(2)+'/'+tD.left(4);
                    
                    dt = Date.parse(tF);         
                    m.DOB__c = dt;
                  
                }
```

Comment: What's the source of the input? Visualforce, Aura, LWC?

Comment: I have the data coming in one object through data loader in text rich area field. I then read the data from that field to create record in another object @sfdcfox

Comment: Oh, I see, you appear to be parsing some sort of CSV, it looks like.

Comment: Yes.please help me as I am stuck and it need to go to production. I do not have any control on input so it need to be done by my class @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you avoid `Date.parse`. You may get random errors depending on the user's locale, given the fixed format of this input. Aside from that, unless you want to do your own calculations, I'd suggest catching the exception:

```
Integer year = Integer.valueOf(tD.left(4));
Integer month = Integer.valueOf(tD.mid(4,2));
Integer day = Integer.valueOf(tD.right(2));
Date parsedDate;
try {
  parsedDate = Date.newInstance(year, month, day);
} catch(Exception e) {
  // Deal with invalid date value here
}
if(parsedDate != null) {
  m.DOB__c = parsedDate;
}
```

This will catch all kinds of scenarios, including invalid date ranges (e.g. past year 4,000), invalid date values (e.g. Feb. 29, 1969), invalid months (e.g. month 13), and so on.

It's also easier to read for future maintenance.